# Print a text file to a specific printer in Python

Tags: python, windows, printing

I want to print a text file to a local printer (name: "XP-58", type: thermal pos printer, op system:windows 8.1) using python.
What is the best way to do it?
I found [this](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/print.html) but I cant find a way to do it.
an optimal solution would be something like this:

1. currentprinter = X
2. tempprinter = "XP-58"
3. open file "test.txt"
4. print to tempprinter
5. set printer to current printer

an extra: do you think it is possible to print barcodes? (different font?)

I tried to use the raw print from the link above, changing it to a function but I dont get anything on my printer. here is my code

```
import os, sys
import win32print

printer_name = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter ()
hPrinter = win32print.OpenPrinter (printer_name)

def prn_txt(text):
    if sys.version_info >= (3,):
      raw_data = bytes (text, "utf-8")
    else:
      raw_data = text
    try:
      hJob = win32print.StartDocPrinter (hPrinter, 1, ("test of raw data", None, "RAW"))
      try:
        win32print.StartPagePrinter (hPrinter)
        win32print.WritePrinter (hPrinter, raw_data)
        win32print.EndPagePrinter (hPrinter)
      finally:
        win32print.EndDocPrinter (hPrinter)
    finally:
      win32print.ClosePrinter (hPrinter)

txt = "blabla"
print prn_txt(txt)
```

but nothing happens?? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: [For barcodes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyBarcode/0.7)

Comment: Printing infrastructure varies wildly between systems and platforms. Your link indicates Windows so I have tagged your question according to that; but please feel free to update your question with details about your platform and environment.

Comment: Done. I forgot to mention it. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

To send text to a printer through the print spooler API you'll want to use `TEXT` mode instead of `RAW`:

```
hJob = win32print.StartDocPrinter (hPrinter, 1, ("Test text document", None, "TEXT"))
```

`RAW` mode is for when you have data such as PCL or Postscript that the printer can process directly. `TEXT` mode will cause the spooler to produce a spool file using a language that the printer understands before sending it to the printer.

Answer (score 0):

txt print specific printer in python

```
import win32print
import win32ui

x = 0
y = 50
printer_name = "EPSON L382 Series (копия 1)"
# if your printer is standard, replace the printer_name:
# win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()

fd = open("file.txt", "r", encoding = "utf-8")
input_string = fd.read()
multi_line_string = input_string.splitlines()

hDC = win32ui.CreateDC()
hDC.CreatePrinterDC()
hDC.StartDoc("Printing...")
hDC.StartPage()
for line in multi_line_string:
hDC.TextOut(x, y, line)
y+=50
hDC.EndPage()
hDC.EndDoc()
fd.close()
```

Comment: Which lines are supposed to be inside the `for` loop, and which outside? Please [edit] and fix the indentation.

Answer (score -1):

you need to change your last line from
print prn_txt(txt)

to just
prn_txt(txt)

the print command writes to console and has nothing to do with printing to printer

Comment:
win32print.StartDocPrinter (hPrinter, 1, ("test of raw data", None, "RAW"))
is correct as "test of raw data" is just the name of the printjob that will show up in the windows printer console.

Comment: While the `print` statement (in Python 2.x code) there is not *helpful*, it is certainly not *causing the reported problem*. `print prn_txt(txt)` will **cause `prn_txt(txt)` to happen first**, and then (assuming the function returns successfully) print the result (`None`).